# Object/Models with dynamic sizes and joint movements

Tags: java, dynamic, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if it is possible with Unity3D to have an object with the following properties, consider a human for example:

- Leg length can be set when you create the object in your game.
- Arm length can be set aswell.
- It can be set for every part of your model.
- Ability to use all joints of bones of your model programatically.

Also is it possible to run Unity3D from Java? Or what would be the best way to get around with Unity3D having a Java background.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of [Joints](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Joint.html) available in Unity3D which you can use with Javascript quite effectively. Check out Character, Fixed and Hinge joints - try adding those components to your gameobject and tweaking their values in the inspector. You can connect items / bones with these and set things like max length, bounciness, breakage points, and more. Once you are comforatable with these you can then add them through code using AddComponent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as scaling your objects you can achieve this by making each joint / portion of the figure a different gameobject, and hold them together in a parent object. Then, you can go through the children of the parents and adjust the local scale of each child using [this.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html)

Im using C# script with my unity project, from a Java background, and I found it pretty easy to pick up -- in general I've thought C# is pretty similar to Java, and C# script I've found to be pretty similar to C#.